# Ruby Overriding Operator

Tags: ruby, operators

I have a class like this:

```
class MyObject
  cattr_accessor :value_     # Note the `cattr_accessor` as opposed to `attr_accessor`.

  def +(right_)
    self.value_ + right_.value_
  end
end
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
x = MyObject.new
y = MyObject.new

x.value_ = 1
y.value_ = 2

puts x + y
```

It's not working though.

Comment: Do you want `value_` to be class or instance variable? `+` works as if it is an instance variable.

Comment: class variable. I see where the problem might be now. But I'd like to see your solution.

Comment: If you want each instance to have a separate value, you need to use `attr_accessor`.

Comment: You're right, it works now with attr_accessor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My method works with attr_accessor.